# how to change x-axis limits ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis, limits

I would like to set limit for x-axis using ggplot bar plot. The whole plot is ok, but when I use ylim(1,6) (these are limits what I need) the bars disappear.

Data:

```
var.A <- as.numeric(c(1:13))
var.B <- c(4.351833, 2.938000, 4.726465, 3.747162, 3.720737, 4.297117, 4.304500, 4.061277, 4.595236, 4.105444, 3.701684, 3.523563, 4.170000)
df <- data.frame(var.A,var.B)
```

Ggplot code:

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(var.A), y=var.B)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", fill="#fff68f", colour="darkgrey", width = 0.4) +
  coord_flip()+
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("aaaaaaa aaaaa","bbbbb bbb bbbb","cccc ccc","dddd dd ddddd",
                            "eee e eeeee e ee","ffffffff","gggggggg","hhhhhhh","iiii",
                            "jjjjjj","kkkkkkk","llllll","mmmmmmmm"))
```

And when I add: `ylim(1,6) +` things are going wrong.

And another thing. The color of every bar is set as `fill="#fff68f"`. Is there any solution to change color of one bar, for example the first from top I'd like to be different, i.e. `#ee2c2c`.

Comment: I did put wrong ggplot code. I missed coord_flip() + Now it's ok,

Comment: Try using `coord_flip(ylim = c(1,6)) `. Have a look at the help for `coord_cartesian`, which explains the difference between the two ways of setting limits. The way you did it, every observation outside the limit is set to `NA`, and since all the bars start at 0, that's all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used `coord_flip()` you can set limits of x-axis with `scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(1,6),oob = rescale_none)` and for setting colors for every bar you can use `scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ee2c2c",...)`.

So if you would like to set the color of bars manually, you first need to create vector of names and insert it in your dataframe:

```
names <- c("aaaaaaa aaaaa","bbbbb bbb bbbb","cccc ccc","dddd dd ddddd",
"eee e eeeee e ee","ffffffff","gggggggg","hhhhhhh","iiii",
"jjjjjj","kkkkkkk","llllll","mmmmmmmm")

var.A <- as.numeric(c(1:13))
var.B <- c(4.351833, 2.938000, 4.726465, 3.747162, 3.720737, 4.297117, 4.304500, 4.061277, 4.595236, 4.105444, 3.701684, 3.523563, 4.170000)
df <- data.frame(var.A,var.B,names)
```

And to order variable names and colors in ggplot you need to change the structure of vector from character to factor (in order to get levels).

```
var.names = factor(df$names,
                levels = c("aaaaaaa aaaaa","bbbbb bbb bbbb","cccc ccc","dddd dd ddddd", "eee e eeeee e ee","ffffffff","gggggggg","hhhhhhh","iiii", "jjjjjj","kkkkkkk","llllll","mmmmmmmm"), ordered=T)
```

So your code then looks like:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=var.names, y=var.B, fill=as.factor(var.names))) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", width = 0.4) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(1,6),oob = rescale_none) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(c(rep("#fff68f",12)),"#ee2c2c"))
```

And output is

[image]